# ER diagram to tables

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams

Consider the following exam question:

[image]

Translation: The INCORRECT transformation from the diagram at the right to tables is...

This is what I think:

a) is incorrect (the column `es_C` (`is_C`) does not make sense to me (is always true)

b) is correct, I don't see anything wrong with it.

c) is incorrect, you cannot represent C which are not S1 nor S2 (and the diagram doesn't say the hierarchy is total)

d) is incorrect. The column `es_C_S1_S2` (`is_C_S1_S2`) does not make sense to me.

There is only one incorrect answer so, can you show me what is wrong with my thinking?

The circled 'd' means disjoint hierarchy, that is, there cannot be a S1 entity which is also a S2 entity.

Comment: Can you comment why the downvote?

Comment: We're not in the habit of answering exam questions.

Comment: @MaxVernon Why? I think is an interesting question, why having appeared in a past exam makes it not a good question to answer?

Comment: Not that. The other "d", in the ER diagram.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I think that is standard for ER diagrams. It means disjoint hierchy, that is, there cannot be a S1 entitiy which is also a S2 entity.

Comment: The `is_C_S1_S2` may mean "is C or is S1 or is S2" for option d. The "is_C" in option a looks redundant indeed but the design has all needed info. So, the INCORRECT answer looks like it is only option c.

Comment: @MaxVernon Exam/course/homework questions are not automatically off-topic. There has been plenty of meta discussion about this e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/194636) and [here](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/490/1192). This question seems on-topic to me.

Comment: @PaulWhite Thanks. It seems like this question will just never be answered because of the downvotes, though =(

Comment: @ypercube Thanks, that makes some sense (the `is_C`being so redundant still bothers me, but I guess you are right, the only completly incorrect is c)